# How to filter the data based on searchbar in Ionic3 and Angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, filter

I have the products api. On my search.html page, I will display the names of all products fetched from json file. How can I achieve names based on the searchbar in the search.html page.I have used the Ionic searchbar component but it didn't work. Please help me. Also post here if any alternative available for this feature.

**search.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-search',
  templateUrl: 'search.html'
  // styleUrls: ['search.scss']
})
export class SearchPage {
  searchQuery: string = '';
  items: any[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private apiService: ApiService) {
     this.initializeItems();
  }

  initializeItems() {
    this.apiService.productsCall().subscribe(response => {
      //console.log(response);
      if(response['status'] == 200) {
        // this.data=response['response'];
        this.items = response['response'];
        console.log(this.items);
      } else if(response['status'] == 500) {
        console.log(response['error'].sqlMessage);

      }
    });
  }  

  getItems(ev: any) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return (item['name'].toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**search.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>

  <ion-list no-lines>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ion-label>{{item.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-avatar item-right>
            <img src='../assets/imgs/medicalStore.png'>
        </ion-avatar>

        <ion-checkbox item-left></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

**json file**

```
{
"status":200,
"error":null,
"response":[
{
"product_id":1,"name":"knee cap","price":1290,"weight":0.4,"short_desc":"Neck Pain Relief Cervical Soft Pillo"
},
{
"product_id":2,"name":"soft pillow","price":1299,"weight":0.3,"short_desc":"Neck Pain Relief Cervical Soft Pillow "
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's a possible way to do it (incomplete)... And maybe I'm over engineering the problem.

Now instead of requerying or whatnot, we can store both the query as well as the data as Observable. While the observable stores the original values we can use various lettable operators such as the `mergeMap` and `map` functions.

The `map` operator lets us modify the value emitted from the observable while leaving the original value in the observable itself. The `mergeMap` allows us to effectively merge two observables. Which in this case is the `_searchQuery` as well as the `_items`. Also we can avoid subscribing to these observable by using the `async` pipe in our template.

When possible I'd advise against using subscribe. While useful, I noticed you were never unsubscribing. Meaning that subscription will stay active, and as you call it the `initializeItems` function again and again you would be instantiating MANY subscriptions. While technically a non issue for HTTP requests (as they terminate themselves), it's good to know/keep in mind.

Let me know if there's anything else!

**search.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-search',
  templateUrl: 'search.html'
})
export class SearchPage {
  private _searchQuery: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  private _items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private apiService: ApiService) {
    this._initializeItems();
  }

  get items(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this._searchQuery.pipe(mergeMap((query: string) => {
      return this._items.pipe(map((items: any[]) => {
        if (query && query.trim() != '') {
          return items.filter((item) => {
            return (item['name'].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1);
          });
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      }))
    })).asObservable();
  }

  private _initializeItems() {
    this._items = this.apiService.productsCall()
      .pipe(map((response) => {
        if (response['status'] == 200) {
          return response['response'];
        } else if (response['status'] == 500) {
          console.log(response['error'].sqlMessage);
          return [];
        }
      }));
  }

  public updateQuery(ev: any) {
    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    const val: string = ev.target.value;
    this._searchQuery.next(val);
  }
}
```

**search.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="updateQuery($event)"></ion-searchbar>

  <ion-list no-lines>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items | async">
        <ion-label>{{item.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-avatar item-right>
            <img src='../assets/imgs/medicalStore.png'>
        </ion-avatar>

        <ion-checkbox item-left></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```